# How to display filename only as an output of cp command?

Tags: linux, command-line, shell, cp

I'm copying files from src folder to dest folder usign the command:

```
cp -nv /src/* /dest/ > copy_result.txt
```

The result of copied files is in the output file as shown below:

```
 « /src/test1.txt » -> « /dest/test1.txt »
 « /src/test2.txt » -> « /dest/test2.txt »
```

Otherwise , I want that the output file contains the filename only, without the whole path and without the file extension, like so:

```
test1
test2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the command

```
cp -nv /src/* /dest/ | awk '{print $6}' | rev | cut -d/ -f1 | rev | cut -d. -f1 > copy_result.txt
```

`awk` prints the sixth field. And `rev` reverses the string. `cut` splits the string at a delimiter specified by `-d`, extract portion specified by `-f`.

Edit:
As pointed out, this is not friendly with files/directories with spaces.
But this will by extracting substrings between '-> « ' and ' »' :

```
cp -nv /src/* /dest/ | sed -e 's/.*-> « \(.*\) ».*/\1/' | rev | cut -d/ -f1 | rev | cut -d. -f1 > copy_result.txt
```

Comment: What about files `/src/with spaces.txt`?

Comment: @Davey The command is working perfectly thank you for your response

Comment: @Davey When running the bash, it says that :  bash: /bin/cp: Argument list too long

Comment: Did you make sure to include the first '|'?  What OS are you on?

Comment: @Davey yes I included '|' ,It's CentOS

Comment: @Angelika You got `argument list too long` because `/src/*` expands to too many entries. Such pattern in `for` loop (like in my answer) is immune to the issue: the long list exists internally in the shell only, no external tool gets a list that is too long. A loop is a common way to deal with the issue; another one is `find -exec` or `find | xargs`.

Answer (score 1):

`-v` is not specified by POSIX. This means each `cp` implementation may handle it differently (or not at all). Where your `cp` says `« foo »` my says `'foo'`. It's possible to craft a command that would transform your undesired output into the desired one, still I'd like to present a solution independent from `cp` implementation.

---

After `/src/*` in your command expands, `cp` copies the resulting entries one by one. This means you can turn `cp -n /src/* /dest/` into

```
for file in /src/*; do cp -n "$file" /dest/; done
```

Now it's easy to do something with `$file`. This will generate the output you want:

```
for path in /src/*; do
   file="${path##*/}"
   dst="/dest/$file"
   [ ! -e "$dst" ] && cp "$path" "$dst" && printf '%s\n' "${file%.*}"
done
```

(To redirect to `copy_result.txt` use `done > copy_result.txt` instead of just `done`).

---

Note if you used `cp -r -v` and at least one of the operands from the expansion of `/src/*` was a directory, `cp` would copy and print its contents, while the above code (after we add `-r`) would copy as much but print only the directory itself. `-r` may not be the only option that would introduce discrepancy.

So while the approach should be independent from `cp` implementation, it relies on some option(s) not being used. Another disadvantage is the code runs a separate `cp` process for every object in `/src/`, this is far from optimal.

There's also a race condition: if the `$dst` file appears between `[` and `cp`, `cp` will do its job. You can use `cp -n` to avoid overwriting, but `printf` will still report the file.

Comment: Please by applying the loop, the new copied file are added with the previous copied files

Comment: @Angelika I don't really understand your comment. Sorry, I'm not a native English speaker. Could you rephrase it?

Comment: Actually when I have used the for loop, The output contains the list of new copied files and also all the previous copied files, normally only the last copied files must be shown in the output

Comment: @Angelika OK, I get it. Added test for nonexistence.

Comment: Thank you for your help now it shows the result of the last copied file